# Adding a figure containg multiple figures inside \twocolumn optional argument

Tags: graphics, subfloats, two-column

I read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145863/can-someone-explain-how-to-fix-this-error-when-trying-to-add-a-picture) that you cannot add a  `\begin{figure}` inside of the optional argument for `\twocolumn`.

I want to add a row that contains 3 images in a twocolumn document.

```
\twocolumn[{
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\maketitle

  \begin{figure}[h]       
  \fbox{\includegraphics{fig1.pdf}}   
  \hspace{30px}
  \fbox{\includegraphics{fig2.pdf}}
  \hspace{30px}
  \fbox{\includegraphics{fig3.pdf}}
  \caption{this is the caption}
  \label{materialflowChart}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{abstract}

  \end{abstract}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
}]
```

Since I cannot use `\begin{figure}` to create my figure, how would I create a row of figures to add inside the `\twocolumn` ?

Comment: Does `'\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` work perhaps?

Comment: Decided to skip the `\begin{figure}` part and just use `\includegraphics` and that worked.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I tried what you suggested, but got the error: "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup."

Comment: Alright, apparently that works for the `twocolumn` option mode only, but not for `\twocolumn` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just drop those dreadful `figure` environments -- if it is not meant to float anyway, just use `\includegraphics` and a `\captionof{figure}{caption text}\label{foo}` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{Theory on Ducks}
\author{Paulo Roberto Massa Cereda (PhD. in Duckumentation)}
\begin{document}

\twocolumn[%
\maketitle

 % \begin{figure}[h]       
  \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente1}}   
  \hspace{30px}
  \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente2}}
  \hspace{30px}
  \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente1}}
  \captionof{figure}{this is the caption}
  \label{materialflowChart}
%  \end{figure}

  \begin{abstract}
\blindtext
  \end{abstract}
]
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]